# Webpack not compiling with React and React Router Dom

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use react and react router dom and all of a sudden I got like 75 errors all saying similar thing to this

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in 'C:\Users\nlowi\Desktop\onlyhands\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
    - install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }
```

Comment: I an receiving the same error, were you able to resolve it?